# adjust text position and rotation in scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have below plotly plot. I would like to put text above the marker 20px and rotate it 25 degree.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
    
fig = go.Figure()

data = [[1,2.3567],
        [2,5.45678],
        [3,1.45678],
        [4,7.45678],
        [5,4.2345]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y'])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y'],
    mode="lines+markers+text",
    name="Lines and Text",
    text=df['y'],
    textfont=dict(
        family="sans serif",
        size=28,
        color="LightSeaGreen"
    )
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [text annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/), eg.

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y'],
    mode="lines+markers",
    name="Lines and Text"
))

for row in df.itertuples():
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=row.x,
        y=row.y,
        text=row.y,
        textangle=-25,
        font=dict(
            family="sans serif",
            size=28,
            color="LightSeaGreen"
        ),
        showarrow=False,
        yshift=20
    )
```

Output :

[image]

See also [Python Figure Reference: layout.annotations](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/)